# @OnClick does not exist in blazor button

Tags: asp.net, blazor

I'm working on making a client-side blazor app and anytime I try to use @onclick It appears not to exist.

The button I use looks like this. I've tried using lowercase, moving the @, and making it a div but I am unsuccessful.
`<asp:button class="Container" @OnClick="(()=>IndexModel.Select(level))">`

I started this app from Visual studio 2019's blazor template so it should be normal.

Comment: Why are you using `<asp:button ... >`  just use <button ... >...</button>.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 1):

That's because `<asp:button ... >` is not Blazor.

This is a normal button declaration on Blazor

```cs
<div class="m-2">
    <button @onclick=OnButtonClick>Click me</button>
</div>

@code {
    private async Task OnButtonClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

You need to read some basic Blazor documentation: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: asp:button was just one attempt at getting this to work. I tried this snipped but @code was not valid. Is it because this is a .cshtml file?

Comment: Yes, if it's a .cshtml file then you need to embed the Blazor component in it.  Normal Blazor components/pages are Razor files.